# discord.js node.js code object promise problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let member = message.guild.members;
      if (command === 'ping') {
            message.channel.send(`${srv.getServerName().then()}`)
        }
});
```

I have a coding like this, when I write ping from the channel, it should write servername but it writes object promise. How can I solve it?
Sorry my english not good, i using google translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `srv.getServerName()` is a Promise, and you're sending it instead of the resolved value to your channel. That's why you see `[object Promise]`.

You can get the server name first and send the message from its `.then()` method:

```
if (command === 'ping') {
  srv
    .getServerName()
    .then(name => message.channel.send(name))
}
```

Or you can make the callback an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and `await` the response before you send it:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const member = message.guild.members;

  if (command === 'ping') {
    const serverName = await srv.getServerName();
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Embed title')
      .setDescription(`This is the "${serverName}" server`);

    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```